# How to save CSS changes from Chrome without workspaces?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

The current workflow for our designer is:

- Opens web page and edit the CSS
- Write up all the CSS changes in an issue

Is there a way for chrome to save the 'diff' of the CSS and export it without using workspaces?

Comment: you can't save changes just directly from browser

Comment: but you can locate the specific css style by following the file and the line number in inspect element

Comment: I made a tiny NodeJS app. I feed it the original CSS and the changed CSS and get a new CSS file with **only** the diff (I use it for the Stylus extension). My app is just a simple wrapper, the code that does the work is an npm package. The one I use is `@romainberger/css-diff`, but there are others.

Answer (score 0):

As of Chrome 65, [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) can help with this. Check your Chrome version at `chrome://version`. If you don't have 65 yet, you can use [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html).

1. Open **Sources**.
2. Click **Local Overrides** tab.

   [image: overrides tab]
3. Click **Select folder for overrides** and choose a destination.
4. Make your changes in the **Styles** pane on **Elements** panel or **Editor** pane in **Sources** panel. Chrome saves the changed files to the specified location.

GOTCHAS!!!

- Changes made in the **DOM Tree** on the **Elements** panel don't get saved.
- Neither do changes made in the **Styles** pane *when the source of the CSS rules is a `<style>` tag in HTML*. At least in Chrome 65. There's rumors that this may get fixed in 66.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if that's what you want, but...

You can edit the page from inspector (ctrl+shift+I) and after done with all your changes, just click on the stylesheet link at your left and copy everything you need [image: Example of what you should click on]